# Why am I able to access a remote s3 bucket data file via pd.read_csv() but not via Athena SQL call like CREATE TABLE?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am curious to know WHY I am able to access a remote s3 bucket's data via pd.read_csv() pandas call from sagemaker studio but NOT via CREATE TABLE call via Athena to access the same bucket?

If anyone knows and can explain it to a noob or can refer me to some documentation to understand and troubleshoot this better, I would really appreciate it!

My colleague has set her s3 bucket as publicly accessible.  So I have coded the following to try to access the bucket data file so that we can work on the same data file and make changes to it etc. BUT the strange thing is, I can load the data via pd.read_csv() call but NOT via Athena SQL CREATE TABLE call.  I am new to AWS and wondering WHY this is the case?

Below is my call to Athena.  My understanding is that I have to CREATE TABLE first before I can run queries on it.  But the create table step throws an error, see code below:

```
import boto3

region = boto3.Session().region_name
session = boto3.session.Session()

ec2 = boto3.Session().client(service_name="ec2", region_name=region)
sm = boto3.Session().client(service_name="sagemaker", region_name=region)

import sagemaker
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
bucket = 'sagemaker-studio-458903497716-h2kl4XXXXX'
region = boto3.Session().region_name

from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(retries={"max_attempts": 10, "mode": "adaptive"})

iam = boto3.client("iam", config=config)

role_name = role.split("/")[-1]

print("Role name: {}".format(role_name))

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
! pip install descartes
! pip install geopandas
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, points_from_xy

import boto3
import sagemaker

sess = sagemaker.Session()
bucket = 'sagemaker-studio-458903497716-h2kl4XXXXX'
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
region = boto3.Session().region_name

!pip install --disable-pip-version-check -q PyAthena==2.1.0
from pyathena import connect

#assign database name
database_name = "ads508"

# Set S3 staging directory -- this is a temporary directory used for Athena queries
s3_staging_dir = "s3://{0}/athena/staging".format(bucket)

conn = connect(region_name=region, s3_staging_dir=s3_staging_dir)

#create new database 'ads508'
statement = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {}".format(database_name)
create_db = pd.read_sql(statement, conn) >>> throws an error
create_db
```

Here is the error it throws on read_sql():

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ads508
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: Unable to verify/create output bucket sagemaker-studio-458903497716-h2kl4ff3dz
```

...

BUT when I try this code it works and loads the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("s3://sagemaker-studio-458903497716-h2kl4XXXXX/data/gun_violence.csv")
df.head()
```

Comment: Might be useful: [Cross-account access in Athena to Amazon S3 buckets - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cross-account-permissions.html)

Comment: FYI, the `s3_staging_dir` is where Athena will store query results. **It is _not_ the location of source data** for running Athena queries. It probably requires write permissions, but you should be using an output location in your _own_ S3 bucket rather than somebody else's bucket.